# How can I apply this css styling to this table in php

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to have the below CSS styling to be applied to the below table being fetched from mysql.

for example when I put

```
echo "<table id="result-table">";
```

right under the $result line it breaks the website.

```html
<style> #result-table {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
}

#result-table td,
#result-table th {
    width: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #2E3A7F;
    text-align: center;
}

#result-table th {
    width: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #6F77A4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
```

```php
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "Not User";
  $password = "Not Password";
  $dbname = "afoam";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tbody>";
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['eid'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['fna'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lna'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
  } else {
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
?>
```

So how can I apply the styling to the table without an issue.

Just to recap I want to apply CSS styling to the Table that is being fetched from mysql.

But I get in error when I enter the CSS id for the styling in the html table brackets

Comment: It's breaking because your PHP syntax is incorrect. You have double quotes for both the string and the class name, which means it's dropping out of the string. Change one set to single quotes.

Comment: use `echo "<table id='result-table'>";`

Comment: Any success with your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to one of the following:

I would prefer:

```php
echo '<table id="result-table">';
```

Or you can switch the quotes, that is a very little bit slower:

```php
echo "<table id='result-table'>";
```

Or you can protect the inner quotes from being executed:

```php
echo "<table id=\"result-table\">";
```